# How to point to templates in django

Tags: django

I am new to code.

I have this code that generates notifications every time an activity related to a given user is done.

At the moment, the notifications are generated and stored to a table.

What I want is to also send the notifications to a related user.

This is the signal that sends an email when a notification is created:

```
def email_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
""" sends an email notification for notifications """

    user = instance.recipient
    recipients = User.objects.filter(email=user)
    deactivation_link = "link.com"

    if created:
       for recipient in recipients:

           if recipient.email_notification is True:
              mail_helper.send_mail(
                subject="Author's Haven notifictions",
                to_addrs=recipient.email,
                multiple_alternatives=True,
                template_name='notifications.html',
                template_values={
                    'username': recipient.username,
                    'optout_link': deactivation_link,
                    'description': instance.description
                }
            )


post_save.connect(email_notification, sender=Notification)
```

The method I am using to send the email is this:

```py
def send_mail(self, subject, message=None,
                  to_addrs=[], multiple_alternatives=False, template_name=None,
                  template_values={}):
        """
            Sends an email using the specified addresses

            Parameters:
            ----------
            subject: str
                Email subject
            to_addrs: list
                Email receipients
            message: str
                Email body (for a plain/text email format)
            multiple_alternatives: boolean
                Send email in text/html format
                If false, email is sent as plain text
            template_name: str
                The path to the HTML template to send email in
                Requires multiple alternatives set to True
            template_values: dict
                key: pair items to render in the template message
        """

        if multiple_alternatives:
            template = render_to_string(template_name, template_values)
            body_msg = strip_tags(template)

            email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject, body_msg, self.sender_email, to_addrs)
            email.attach_alternative(template, 'text/html')
            email.send()

        elif not multiple_alternatives:
            _send_mail(subject, message, to_addrs)
```

This is my email template:

```html
{% extends 'authors/apps/authentication/templates/emailing_template.html' %}
{% block body %}

Here
    <div id="email-verification">
        <p id="greeting">Hey <span id="name">{{ username }}</span>,</p>
        <p id="text-body"><span id="shout">Yaaay!</span> You are now on Authors' Haven.</p>
        <p> Click on the button below to activate your account: </p>
            <div id="activation-button">
               <p>{{ description }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="failed-button">
                <p>If the button doesn't work, copy the link below and paste it in your browser:
                {{ activation_link }}</p>
            </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, here is my folder structure:

```py
authors/apps/notifications/
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── renderers.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── serializers.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── signals.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
├── renderers.py
├── serializers.py
├── signals.py
├── templates
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── notifications.html
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── test_notifications.cpython-36-PYTEST.pyc
│   └── test_notifications.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

This generates the notifications but does not send it to the user's email. It raises the error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /api/articles/
authors/apps/authentication/templates/emailing_template.html
```

How do I get django to send the email with the template?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "point to the template instead of the endpoint". And where are you referencing "emailing_template.html"?

Comment: It is an API I am working on using drf. By endpoints, I mean the API endpoints. However, emails need templates to render to the user's email. The 'emailing_template.html' is defined as a base template and I am simply extending it in my 'notificatios.html'.

Comment: But your question is still unclear. What do you mean by "pointing" to a template? In what way is that being confused with endpoints? Also, please show the full traceback, and the part of notifications.html that references emailing_template.html.

Comment: Okay. Let me make the updates.

Comment: 'emailing_template.html' is in another submodule for authentication

Answer (score 1):

You have put the full path in your `extends` tag. You need to just put the path from a template directory. So it should just be `{% extends "emailing_template.html" %}`.

Note, you should not be putting your app directories in the template DIRS setting. That is for the main project-level template directory. You should remove those values.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will make the updates. In practice, how do you implement endpoints that are to be rendered in emails? 

Like activation links or as in my case, email notifications?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. To generate a URL, you can use the `{% url %}` tag like you would in any other template.

Comment: Made the changes. And the error is `TemplateDoesNotExist at /api/articles/`. `/api/articles/` is my endpoint for creating articles. When articles are created, activity should be generated in the notification module and be sent emails using the `notifications.html` template. So why is Django looking for the template at `/api/articles/` and how do I get it to look for the template in the right folder?

Comment: It's not. That's just telling you the URL you requested, which triggered the event. The rest of the message tells you what template it was that wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Are your templates in a folder with the name of the app *inside* of the app/template folder?  It seemed redundant to me, when I first learned about it. But, you can then reference a template as 'appname/tamplatename.html', even in another app.

E.g., I think your email template should be in notifications/templates/notifications/emailing_template.html
then your template_name becomes 'notifications/emailing_template.html'